# Can we create "Send http request to sharepoint" action, to create a Share link to specific external users without sending them direct invitation email

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, power-automate, external-sharing

Using SharePoint Online UI >> we can share a document with specific external users (with Read-Only permission) using those steps:-

[image: image.png]

[image]

[image: image.png]

now we are developing power automate flow, which need to create similar share links, but without sending a direct email to the external users' emails >> instead we want to get the sharing link >> prepare an custom HTML table which contain the share link address and then send the HTML table to the external users later on.

so can we do so using SharePoint REST API ? and how?

Regards